# Find text & insert range 7 rows above & shift down

Tags: excel, vba, insert, find

---

Hi I have recurring text in a column that says: " **"command": 16,** "

Every time that text occurs I want to insert a set range from sheet 2, 7 rows above

I have this code but can't get it working.. any ideas

```
Sub Find_Insert()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim m As Long
Dim Lastrow2 As Long

Sheets("servo commands").Range("B1:B192").Copy 'sheet with set range to copy

Worksheets("Import").Activate
Lastrow2 = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
For m = Lastrow2 To 1 Step -1
    If Cells(m, "A").Value = "                ""command"": 16," Then Cells(m, "A").Offset(-7, 0).Select
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown

Next
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

many thanks in advance

Comment: Put a breakpoint on the line where the loop starts, then check your variables. Also, qualify your cells/ranges instead of relying on which sheet is active at the time. You are just asking for problems when they are not qualified.

Answer (score 1):

### Insert Range With Offset

```vb
Sub InsertCells()
    
    Const DST_ROW_OFFSET As Long = 7
    Const DST_CRIT_STRING As String = "                ""command"": 16,"
    
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = wb.Sheets("Servo Commands")
    Dim srg As Range: Set srg = sws.Range("B1:B192")
    
    Dim dws As Worksheet: Set dws = wb.Sheets("Import")
    Dim dlRow As Long: dlRow = dws.Cells(dws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    Dim dr As Long, dString As String
    
    For dr = dlRow To DST_ROW_OFFSET + 1 Step -1
        dString = CStr(dws.Cells(dr, "A").Value)
        If StrComp(dString, DST_CRIT_STRING, vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
            srg.Copy
            dws.Cells(dr, "A").Offset(-DST_ROW_OFFSET).Insert Shift:=xlShiftDown
            dr = dr - DST_ROW_OFFSET
        End If
    Next dr
    
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

    MsgBox "Cells inserted."

End Sub
```

Comment: Thankyou @VBasic2008 it appears to work for the first instance, then the remainder of the instances above, it inserts a blank row.. I have had a play round with this but dont see anything obvious.. is it perhaps, loosing the memory of what was copied?

Comment: Sorry, my sample data was too simple. Fixed it.

Comment: Brilliant, @VBasic2008 works exactly as needed. Thank you.